# Groovy script to check if a webpage returns 504

Tags: groovy

How can we check if a page returns 504 using groovy script. Please help.

I need to check if a webpage returns 504 and if it returns 504 I need to fail the jenkins build.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this (simple, won't require additional dependencies and seems to fit your needs):

```
HttpURLConnection connection = new URL("http://google.com/").openConnection();
def resoponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

connection.disconnect();

println("The response code was ${resoponseCode}")
```

If google is up :-) responseCode will be 200. Then you may write:

```
if (responseCode ...) {
   // fail the build here
}
```

Hope it helps.